# Arraylist of objects to Array of strings

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I'm trying to convert an ArrayList that contains "cards", or objects that store two numbers, a rank and a suit. Normally to get a single instance of the card, I use:

```
dealer.dealerhand.get(1).showstats();
```

Where showstats returns a string and is:

```
public String showstats()
{
    String realsuit = "";
    if(this.suit == 0)
    {
        realsuit = "Diamonds";
    }
    else if(this.suit == 1)
    {
        realsuit ="Hearts";
    }
    else if(this.suit == 2)
    {
        realsuit = "Clubs";
    }
    else if(this.suit == 3)
    {
        realsuit = "Spades";
    }
    String str = "My rank is: " + this.rank + " My Suit is: " + realsuit;
    return str;
}
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
 public String[] getStats()
{
    String[] dealerstats = this.dealerhand.toArray(new String[this.dealerhand.size()]);
    return dealerstats;
}
```

and

```
 public String[] getStats()
{
    String[] dealerstats = {""};
    for(int i = 0; i < this.dealerhand.size(); i++)
    {
        dealerstats[i] = (dealerhand.get(i).showstats());
    }
    return dealerstats;
}
```

But they both don't work. The end goal would be a string array of the cards in the dealerhand ArrayList, that I will print out using JList. Thanks!

Comment: What goes worng with what you've tried?

Comment: The last part seems correct, do you get an error?

Comment: It throws: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at BlackJack.Dealer.getStats(Dealer.java:124)
 at BlackJack.Dealer.main(Dealer.java:150)
line 124 is dealerstats[i] = (dealerhand.get(i).showstats());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this:

```
 public String[] getStats() {
    for(int i = 0; i < this.dealerhand.size(); i++) {
        dealerstats[i] = (dealerhand.get(i).showstats());
    }
    return dealerstats;
}
```

make sure to initialize your String array, such as below:

```
 public String[] getStats(Dealer dealer) { // Input a dealer
    String[] dealerstats = new String[dealer.dealerhand.size()]; // Initialize String array
    for(int i = 0; i < this.dealerhand.size(); i++) {
        dealerstats[i] = dealerhand.get(i).showstats();
    }
    return dealerstats;
}
```

I am also assuming you have a `Dealer` object, as you seem to reference one in your question.

Comment: Thanks, it gave me [Ljava.lang.String;@56f7ce53 when I printed it to console. It seems like such a stupid mistake

Comment: @user3413170 You are printing the address.  How are you printing it?

Comment: System.out.println(dealer.getStats()); This is only to test if the method actually works. I need to call it in the controller class so ultimately it ends up in the JFrame.

Comment: It works, and shows the correct information with my JFrame controller. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt is almost correct. You created the array but without giving it the correct size. The `String[] dealerstats`  size should be the size of the ArrayList `dealerhand`:

```
public String[] getStats()
{
    String[] dealerstats = new String[ dealerhand.size() ];

    for( int i = 0; i < dealerstats.length; ++i )
         dealerstats[i] = dealerhand.get(i).showstats();

    return dealerstats;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a `toString()` method in your `Card` class you can print the `ArrayList` out without any conversion ([Live Ideone Example here](https://ideone.com/EXv9fy)):

```
public class Card{
    ...
    @Override public String toString(){
        return "My rank is: " + this.rank + " My Suit is: " + this.suit;
    }
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
List<Card> dealerCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
dealerCards.add(new Card(5, "Hearts"));
dealerCards.add(new Card(10, "Diamonds"));

System.out.println(dealerCards);
```

---

**Output:** `["My rank is: 5 My Suit is: Hearts", "My rank is: 10 My Suit is: Diamonds"]`

Comment: Actually this is extremely helpful. I went ahead and used kevinrmannix's solution, but I will try this out.

Comment: No problem. If you want a more Object Oriented approach this will improve your code's clarity and length in the long run.